# PowerShell - Special Date Format

Tags: powershell, getdate

I'd like to have an output of get-date for the current day in PowerShell to the following format:

11-Apr-2018

I've tried playing around with this and have not been successful. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy"
```

Formatting strings follow .NET standards.

See also official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6).

Answer (score 0):

If you did a little bit of research, you will find a list with all the date format patterns and the description to them aswell
here https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-dateformats.html

In your case

```
Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy"
```